# Outlook VBA - Move only emails from conversation that are still in inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I have adjusted a routine found on the internet in Outlook VBA that moves all emails from a conversation in inbox to a specific folder.

I move my emails by getting them like:

```
olItem As MailItem 'Put email from conversation in olItem
DestFolder As Outlook.Folder 'Destination folder where i want to send my email
olItem.Move DestFolder
```

Problem is: in this conversation I have sometimes older emails that have already been moved to the destination folder earlier: they appear in my inbox because of the way conversation mode works.

If I try to move it with *olItem.Move DestFolder*, the code fails as the email is already in DestFolder.

**How to detect if an email is already in the destination folder and move it to ONLY if it's not there already**

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method that may suffice.

```
On Error Resume Next
olItem.Move DestFolder
' Turn error bypass off once the purpose for it has been served
On Error GoTo 0
```